# android crash while inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

i have this method for inflating and storing the views in a hashmap

```
private void changeRecyclerViewHeader(int header) {
    if (recyclerViewHeaders.containsKey(header)) {
        _headerView = recyclerViewHeaders.get(header);
    } else {
        _headerView = ((Holder) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(header, (ViewGroup) _productsRV.getParent(), false);
        recyclerViewHeaders.put(header, _headerView);
    }
    _adapter.setHeaderView(_headerView);
}
```

and i call it with the resourceID like this:

```
changeRecyclerViewHeader(R.id.someLayoutName);
```

the problem is when i get to this line (the first line in the else) :

```
_headerView = ((Holder) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(header, (ViewGroup) _productsRV.getParent(), false);
```

i get a crash:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090085 type #0x12 is not valid
```

any help?

Comment: You should supply a layout (`R.layout.x`) and not a resource id (`R.id.x`) to inflate().

Comment: thanks man, saved me

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate some layout in recyclerview. You are using `R.id.someLayoutName`. Use `R.layout.someLayoutName` instead of it. This will solve your error.